# Inefficient Parsec parser to skip unreachable block

Tags: haskell, parsec

In a parser written with Parsec 3.1.11, I have a performance issue with parsing (or better, skipping) the unreachable branch of a if-then-else statement.

The syntax to be parsed is as follows:

```
_if (condition) {
  # block of statements
} _else {
  # block of statements
}
```

The `_else` branch is optional and only statically resolvable conditions are allowed.

The parser for the `if-then-else` block:

```hs
type MyParser a = ParsecT T.Text UserState (StateT UserState Identity) a

ifelseStmt :: MyParser -> [Statement]
  = do  reserved "_if"
        e <- parens expression
        if evalBoolExpr e
          then do b <- block
                  option [] $
                    do reserved "_else"
                       unparsedBlock
                  return b
          else do unparsedBlock
                  option [] $
                    do reserved "_else"
                       block
```

Now, parser `unparsedBlock` is meant to throw away the entire `{...}` block of the unreachable branch. Obviously this can in turn contain `{..}` blocks, which means curly brackets have to be matched.

This is the parser I wrote for it:

```
unparsedBlock :: MyParser -> [Statement]
  = do braces (many (do { noneOf "{}"; return []}  <|> unparsedBlock))
       return []
```

It works well, but the profiler shows that way too much time is spent on it, while I'd expect it to be rather efficient.

Can anyone see how I could implement `unparsedBlock` more efficiently?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you can batch the skipping of braces (and return `()`):

```
unparsedBlock :: Parser ()
unparsedBlock = braces (skipMany (skipMany (noneOf "{}") <|> unparsedBlock))
```

Unfortunately, this is also probably quite inefficient, as this still works on a character-by-character basis, and uses stuff like [manyAccum](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/parsec-3.1.11/docs/Text-Parsec.html#v:manyAccum) under the hood.

If you really need more speed, then you will need to write your own `Parser` function that does the skipping on the source, while at the same time updating the position in the stream.

That is (one of) the reason(s) `attoparsec` is much faster : it doesn't keep track of the position in the input stream, and has combinators that work directly on the source (such as [skipWhile](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/attoparsec-0.13.1.0/docs/Data-Attoparsec-Text.html#v:skipWhile)).

Comment: The character by character parsing seems the real issue indeed. Somewhat related to this discussion btw: https://github.com/mrkkrp/megaparsec/issues/106